# smoothness of map from general linear group to symmetric matrices (manifolds)

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Let $GL(n,R)$ be general linear group and $S(n,R)$ be set of symmetric matrices. Both viewed as manifolds.
Let $f: GL(n,R)->S(n,R), f(A)=A^TA$

I want to prove that $f$ is smooth map. How do I do it?

I wanted to consider coordinate representation of $f$, but I don't know what is smooth structure for $GL(n,R)$ and $S(n,R)$.

I know that smooth structure for vector space is just one chart: the whole space with the map that after the base is chosen maps vectors to its coordinates in this basis. (*)

I know that if we have an open subset $U$ of manifold $M$ then we can get an atlas for $U$ (thought of as a manifold on its own) by taking charts $(V,\varphi)$ of $M$ such that $V \subset U$ (**)

In my case set of matrices $M(n,R)$ is manifold and a vector space so it has smooth structure (*), $GL(n,R)$ is open subset of it, but I can't use atlas (**) because there is no such chart.

Comment: It's a polynomial map. $GL_n$ has a smooth structure inherited from $M_n$ and symmetric matrices form a vector space.

Comment: $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a smooth submanifold of $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ as you said, which is diffeomorph to the space $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.
On the other hand, symmetric matrices are a linear space (linearly) isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)/2}$, so the map $A \mapsto A^tA$ is just component-wise given as sums and products, hence polynomial in each component. By some standard more-dimensional analysis results, this is a smooth map between your spaces.

Comment: What is inherited smooth structure? Can you write it explicitly? I tried to do it and I couldn't, as I described in post.

Comment: $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is an open subset of $M(n,\mathbb{R})$ and hence inherits the natural smooth structure from the identity chart.

Comment: Can someone write it more concretely or send me a good source where I can read about this? I am reading introduction to smooth manifolds John M. Lee and I tried to use smooth structure for vector spaces for M(n,R) and smooth structure for open subsets of manifolds for GL(n,R) and it does not work as I said in the post.